# How to getting around pywinauto's ElementAmbiguousError: There are 2 elements that match the criteria error

Tags: python, criteria, pywinauto, ambiguous

I am trying to automate running [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) using python and pywinauto.
So far I have been able to run the executable and modify the controls on Rufus' main screen.
After the code I have written clicks the "START" button, Rufus displays a popup.
This popup is warning you that the whole contents of the USB key are going to be erased.
What I am unable to do is to connect to that popup and press the "OK" button there.

Here is the code I have written:

```
# Connect to an existing window with title matching a regular expression
def ConnectWindow(exp):
  # Look for window matching regular expression
  try:
    handles = pwa.findwindows.find_windows(found_index=0, title_re=exp)
  except pwa.findwindows.WindowNotFoundError:
    handles = None
  # Make sure something was found
  if handles:
    # Make sure only one found
    if len(handles) > 1:
      print('Matched more than one window matching regular expression: {0}'.format(exp))
      sys.exit(1)
    # Return it!
    return pwa.Application().connect(handle=handles[0]).window()
  # Nothing found
  return None

popup = ConnectWindow('^Rufus$')
popup.set_focus()
pwa.keyboard.send_keys('{RIGHT}{ENTER}')
```

ConnectWindow does find the window and popup is of type pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification.
However, whenever I try to do anything with popup (such as set_focus) I get the following error:
***pywinauto.findwindows.ElementAmbiguousError: There are 2 elements that match the criteria {'backend': 'win32', 'process': 32992}***
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I see you don't accept other's answers as correct. It doesn't motivate to write answers. Just FYI.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, I did a search for the answer and I must not have found the other answer to which you refer.  I am very sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this code could be written much more compact. Please don't use `find_windows` function directly. Read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) to learn how WindowSpecification's work.

```
app = pwa.Application(backend="win32").connect(found_index=0, title_re=exp, timeout=10)
popup = app.window(found_index=0, title_re=exp)

popup.type_keys('{RIGHT}{ENTER}') # it calls .set_focus() inside
```

Comment: There is a gray check box under voting buttons at the left side of the answer. It should work to mark the answer as accepted. It will show others who scrolling the feed that the problem has been resolved.

Comment: Done!  Thanks for the help.